# Git forgets patch history after merge

Tags: git, git-merge

I have master and 2 feature branches like so:
[image]

At some point f2.2 got merged into the other branches (had to do manual merging into master via procedure outlined in the rounded square).
Now i am running git log between **m5** and **w3.3**. I don't expect to see f2.2 in there because this change has been merged into both branches - but it is there. Moreover, if you run blame in m5, f2.2 is not shown as the origin of the change but f2.3(result of the merge) is shown instead. During the merge, i didn't even touch that particular file - it has been auto-merged.

I have two questions:

1. Is there way to resolve merge conflicts without making git forget
   the true origin of change (in case of automatic merge at least)? (i
   don't consider fast forward a merge)
2. My workflow is clearly broken. Being able to easily check what
   commits differ between branches is very important for our highly
   distributed and unorganized team. Any best practices that would help
   us avoid the problem described here?

Comment: I don't see a problem here.  Commit `f2.2` is definitely a parent of `m5`, so you should not be surprised to see `f2.2` in the history.

Comment: I was hoping to not see commits that are in **both** branches when checking for difference **between** branches.

git log origin/master..origin/new_feature --oneline --no-merges

Comment: I think the issue here is that merge commits have two parents.  Assuming you only wanted to follow one path looking backwards, what would that path be?

Comment: I've created a new Repo with exactly the commits shown in your diagram. git log m5..w3.3 --no-merges gives me w3.2 and w3.1 which I think is exactly what you expected. I fear there's something wrong with your diagram.

Comment: hi Marcus! I really appreciate the effort you taken to re-create this in git. Any chance you could share your repo so that i could see what is different?

Comment: Look here: https://github.com/MSchmidke/andrewbutenko